# Is NS_AVAILABLE_IOS undocumented API?

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to use it as part of my Xcode documentation so it detects and adds this as part of the document, but I'm not sure if Apple considers this undocumented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not undocumented, it's defined in **Foundation.framework -> NSObjCRuntime.h**

```
#define NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(_ios) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA, __IPHONE_##_ios)
```

Comment: you're right , as of iOS 5 it is in official documentation, ( https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS50APIDiff/ )

Answer (score 1):

It is just a macro - not an actual API for IDE documentation / hints , it should not affect much so you should be fine

perhaps go see this thread for some more information : [Catching NS_AVAILABLE_IOS while coding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12691673/catching-ns-available-ios-while-coding)